# The .keyup function isn't being triggered

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, keyup

I'm  trying to get my program to calculate a function automatically while the user is typing in the numeric values. For some reason, the **.keyup** function isn't being recognized.

I've even tried adding an **Alert()** function just to see if it was making it to the *keyup* event, but to no avail. And after tinkering, I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

The code is below... Please excuse the excessive amount of css code, I only added it for congruency.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // var value = $("#inputID").val();

  // input formatting
  $('.amount').mask('#,###.##', {
    reverse: true
  });

  var bal = $('#balance').val();
  var daily = $('#percentage').val();
  var ppd = $('#pips').val();

  var lotsize = (bal * daily) / ppd;

  $('.entry').keyup(
    function() {
      $('#LotSize').val(lotsize);
    });
});
```

```css
=====LEVEL 1. RESET STYLES=====*/ .field {
  --uiFieldPlaceholderColor: var(--fieldPlaceholderColor, #767676);
}

.field__input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.field__input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--uiFieldPlaceholderColor);
}

.field__input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--uiFieldPlaceholderColor);
  opacity: 1;
}


/*
=====
LEVEL 2. CORE STYLES
=====
*/

.a-field {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a-field__input {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.a-field__input:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/*
=====
LEVEL 3. PRESENTATION STYLES
=====
*/


/* a-field */

.a-field {
  --uiFieldHeight: var(--fieldHeight, 40px);
  --uiFieldBorderWidth: var(--fieldBorderWidth, 2px);
  --uiFieldBorderColor: var(--fieldBorderColor);
  --uiFieldFontSize: var(--fieldFontSize, 1em);
  --uiFieldHintFontSize: var(--fieldHintFontSize, 1em);
  --uiFieldPaddingRight: var(--fieldPaddingRight, 15px);
  --uiFieldPaddingBottom: var(--fieldPaddingBottom, 15px);
  --uiFieldPaddingLeft: var(--fieldPaddingLeft, 15px);
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: var(--uiFieldFontSize);
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.a-field__input {
  height: var(--uiFieldHeight);
  padding: 0 var(--uiFieldPaddingRight) 0 var(--uiFieldPaddingLeft);
  border-bottom: var(--uiFieldBorderWidth) solid var(--uiFieldBorderColor);
}

.a-field__input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.a-field__input::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.a-field__input:not(:placeholder-shown)~.a-field__label-wrap .a-field__label {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: var(--uiFieldPaddingBottom);
}

.a-field__input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.a-field__input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.a-field__label-wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--uiFieldHeight);
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: text;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.a-field__label {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--uiFieldPaddingLeft);
  bottom: calc(50% - .5em);
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: var(--uiFieldHintFontSize);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: bottom .2s cubic-bezier(0.9, -0.15, 0.1, 1.15), opacity .2s ease-out;
  will-change: bottom, opacity;
}

.a-field__input:focus~.a-field__label-wrap .a-field__label {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: var(--uiFieldHeight);
}


/* a-field_a1 */

.a-field_a1 .a-field__input {
  transition: border-color .2s ease-out;
  will-change: border-color;
}

.a-field_a1 .a-field__input:focus {
  border-color: var(--fieldBorderColorActive);
}


/* a-field_a2 */

.a-field_a2 .a-field__label-wrap::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  height: var(--uiFieldBorderWidth);
  background-color: var(--fieldBorderColorActive);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  will-change: width;
  transition: width .285s ease-out;
}

.a-field_a2 .a-field__input:focus~.a-field__label-wrap::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/* a-field_a3 */

.a-field_a3 {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.a-field_a3 .a-field__label-wrap::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  border: var(--uiFieldBorderWidth) solid var(--fieldBorderColorActive);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  will-change: opacity, height;
  transition: height .2s ease-out, opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.a-field_a3 .a-field__input:focus~.a-field__label-wrap::after {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.a-field_a3 .a-field__input:focus~.a-field__label-wrap .a-field__label {
  bottom: calc(var(--uiFieldHeight) + .5em);
}


/*
=====
LEVEL 4. SETTINGS
=====
*/

.field {
  --fieldBorderColor: #D1C4E9;
  --fieldBorderColorActive: #673AB7;
}


/*
=====
DEMO
=====
*/

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Open Sans, Ubuntu, Fira Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  order: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .page {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <label class=" field a-field a-field_a2">
      <input id="balance" class="amount field__input a-field__input" placeholder="e.g. $500" required>
      <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
        <span class="a-field__label">Current Balance</span>
      </span>
   </label>
    <label class="field a-field a-field_a2">
      <input id="daily" class="amount field__input a-field__input" placeholder="e.g. 15" required>
      <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
        <span class="a-field__label">Daily Percentage Goal</span>
      </span>
 </label>
    <label class="field a-field a-field_a2">
      <input id="pips" class=" field__input a-field__input" placeholder="e.g. 50" required>
      <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
        <span class="a-field__label">Average Pips Per Day</span>
      </span>
   </label>
    <label class="field a-field a-field_a2">
      <input id="LotSize" class="field__input a-field__input" readonly required>
      <span class="a-field__label-wrap">
        <span class="a-field__label">Lot Size</span>
      </span>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="linkedin">
    <div class="linkedin__container">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `entry` class doesn't appear in your HTML / none of your controls have class 'entry' for the key up function to be applied to.

Comment: You'll also want to move the `$("#id").val()` code *inside* the keyup function - these are not "live" values and will not change once read.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I really appreciate it.
I made both changes. So now the keyup is being called. However, I'm getting a **NaN** for my answer. Do you see any issues with my arithmetic? 

I tried changing the equation to use modulus, and i also split the equation down into two parts, and I'm still getting a **NaN** result.

Comment: You just need to **look at what you're getting**.  If you look at `$('#balance').val();` you'll see it includes commas, eg `1,234.56` - this is not a valid format for a number so javascript can't coerce it to a number when you use it as a number with `*`.

Comment: Possibly: see https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html `$('.date').cleanVal();` -- change `.val()` to `.cleanVal()`  - but looks like it removes `.` as well, which is pretty useless.  Read those docs more to see if there's a method to get it out or you'll have to convert the comma version yourself (search on SO for numerous answers on this)

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look into it.